# How to order request parameters in OAuth2 url using npm passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I've able to successfully using Oauth2 strategies like Github and Twitter to login to web application using npm passort.

Now I want to login using new globalid authentication.

You can check it out here https://developer.global.id it is pretty cool stuff.

If I am using https://oauthdebugger.com to try connect using my client_id etc.
I receive a well formatted url that's working with globalid service.
Therefore, all the configurations should be right such as authentication url, callback url...

It generates a url in format:

```
https://auth.globalid.net
?client_id=549b156e-dfeb-431a-b1b7-c055e6bc0ea4
&redirect_uri=https://junglekino.azurewebsites.net/api/auth/globalid/callback
&scope=public
&response_type=code
&response_mode=form_post
&nonce=rqxann0hckn
```

Within my node.js application I use the Oauth2Strategy to generate the Oauth call.
This is done with:

```
'use strict';
var passport = require('passport'),
  OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth2').Strategy,
  users = require('../../controllers/users.server.controller');

module.exports = function (config) {
  // Use default oauth2 strategy for GlobaliD login
  passport.use(new OAuth2Strategy({
    authorizationURL: config.globalid.authorizationURL,
    tokenURL: 'https://auth.globalid.net', // not sure if I need this?',
    clientID: config.globalid.clientID,
    clientSecret: config.globalid.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: config.globalid.callbackURL
  },
  function (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    // Set the provider data and include tokens
    var providerData = profile._json;
    providerData.accessToken = accessToken;
    providerData.refreshToken = refreshToken;
    // Create the user OAuth profile
    var providerUserProfile = {
      firstName: profile.name.givenName,
      lastName: profile.name.familyName,
      displayName: profile.displayName,
      email: profile._json.email,
      username: profile.username,
      provider: 'globalid',
      providerIdentifierField: 'user_id',
      providerData: providerData
    };
  }));
};
```

But this code leads to this badly formatted url and therefore authentication does not work:

```
https://auth.globalid.net/
?response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://junglekino.azurewebsites.net/api/auth/globalid/callback
&client_id=549b156e-dfeb-431a-b1b7-c055e6bc0ea4
```

So the origin of this issue seems pretty clear - 
If I extend the list of parameters accordingly to the working url, it is still not working. Therefore, I think, the url parameters must also be in right order as well - but how would I achieve this? Where is the place to configure such a thing?

Please, let me know if you need some other information.

Thanks!

Best Regards,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

I've did some further research.
It seems that the default authentication strategy by passport is requesting a `response_type=code` instead of `response_type=token`. This is hardcoded within the strategy.js of the passport-OAuth2.0 module. In order to use the GlobaliD OAuth authentication a new passport strategy for globaliD has to be written here:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/wiki/Strategies

Unfortunately this is not possible with my skill level :-/

Best regards,

Chris